# php access mysql localhost and remote host

Tags: php

I change between localhost and remote host dev: I test it on localhost and then I copy the files to remote in php.

I have one class MYDB which stores the host and user-db info in constants.
How can I declare the constants and write MYDB so that I do not have to switch manually between these two access dates.Instead, I want to switch automatically.
I use:

```
host: localhost
user: timo
db: localhostdb
pwd: ...

 host: remotehostname
 user: timo
 db: remotehostdb
  pwd:..
```

Before I switch to localhost, I comment the remote host and vice versa. This is not good.
Any idea ?
Timo

Comment: as localhost can work on remote and local because for remote host is normally localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About good. Some other approaches

1. Some people maintain different files between production and local testing
2. You could wrap the code around if($production) .. else ..... Then set that production variable automatically. e.g. we do it based on the URL. If the URL is production URL, then the  $production is set to production.

Answer (score 3):

I handle this by storing the credentials in a `config.live.php` file, which can be overwritten with the existence of a `config.test.php` file.

When including the config:

```
require_once(file_exists('config.test.php') ? 'config.test.php' : 'config.live.php');
```

I keep the `config.live.php` versioned and the `config.test.php` ignored by SVN. This way, the test file never ends up in production, and anyone who checks out a copy of the code can copy the live.php to a new test.php file and update their test config.

Answer (score 2):

How I solved it:

class MyDB {

```
private static $db;

static public function getInstance($Start = false) {

if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'localhost') {

/*  $DB_HOST = 'localhost'; 
    $DB_DATABASE = ''; 

    $DB_USER = ''; 
    $DB_PASSWORD = '';
*/  
    $aConnection = array('DB_HOST' => 'localhost', 'DB_DATABASE' => '', 'DB_USER' => '', 'DB_PASSWORD' => '');
} else {

    $aConnection = array('DB_HOST' => 'd', 'DB_DATABASE' => '', 'DB_USER' => '', 'DB_PASSWORD' => $DB_PASSWORD);

}

    if (!self::$db) {
        self::$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $aConnection['DB_HOST'] . ';dbname=' . $aConnection['DB_DATABASE'] , $aConnection['DB_USER'], $aConnection['DB_PASSWORD'], array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, 
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    }

    echo mysql_error();

    if ($Start)
        return $aConnection;
    else #Normale pdo klasse
        return self::$db;
}
```

}

So if I need a normal mysql connection, I use the array, if I need PDO, I use the static db Variable.